# Can a bounded function be monotonically increasing for all x>0?

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

Can we have a function such that it is **always increasing** for all x>0 and is also **bounded above** by some real number? How do we prove or disprove this statement?(The above statement is not a problem itself, this concept is required in another problem, so I want some help regarding it!)

Comment: Note, "*always increasing*" does not imply that it is always increasing by the same amount... The amount it increases by can be smaller and smaller each time.  Consider by analogy the infinite sum $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}=2$ where at each step we add half of what we added in the previous step.  You should have seen that sum before and should have seen the corresponding partial sum, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{2^n}=2-2^{-N}$

Comment: So, if I want to add another requirement like the derivative of the function is also strictly increasing for all x>0, can we still have a function matching the above requirements and the latest one as well?

Comment: No.  The only thing which allowed this to exist was a decreasing derivative.  If the derivative was static or increasing then you will be unbounded and growing indefinitely and this should be easy to prove.

Comment: Yeah I had guessed so. But I haven't been able to prove this. Can you give me some lead?

Comment: Suppose $f'(x)>\epsilon$ for all $x>x_0$.  Then $f(x+1)>f(x)+\epsilon$ and in general $f(x+M/ \epsilon)>f(x)+M$ for any $M$ and $x>x_0$... in particular any proposed upper bound $M$.  This should follow from Rolles' or MVT or something like that if you can phrase it correctly.  The only thing left is to massage the proof to account for if $f(x_0)$ was negative, but that should be as simple as adjusting the value inside the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, I'm a beginner in calculus and working my way through proofs for the first time!

Answer (score 3):

Consider a function such as $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$, or $g(x)=\arctan{(x)}$, or $h(x)=1-\frac{1}{x}$. These all satisfy the requirement you've given, being bounded above by $1, \frac{\pi}{2}, 1$, respectively.